# Typescript- set property to object

Tags: javascript, object, typescript

One question about Objects in JS ( typescript ). I have following code which works fine

```
myObj: { type: string } = { type: '' };
this.myObj.type = 'Abcd';
```

But i want this code to work

```
myObj: { type: string };
this.myObj.type = 'abcd'; // this.myObj['type'] = 'Abcd'; also not working
```

Why is it not working? What am i doing wrong?
I am getting 'cannot set property type of null'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
let myObj: { type: string };
```

Compiles to this javascript:

```
var myObj;
```

As you can see, you're not assigning a value to it, so if you'll try to do:

```
myObj.type = "what not";
```

You'll get an error becaue `myObj` is undefined.

You can do this:

```
let myObj = { type: '' };
```

The compiler will infer the right type for `myObj`.
This way it will have a value and you won't have to write both the value and the type.

Comment: So if i do let myObj = { }; and after this myObj['type']='abcd'; it's ok?

Comment: Yes, but you won't have type safety.

Comment: sadly, thought that i can do this without initialization. Okay, thanks :)